# Split column in length using Python

Tags: python, split, row

I want to split one column into multiple in Python (in vertical direction). If I google, I can only find the split function, that splits in horizontal direction:
|1,2,3| --> |1|2|3|

However, I want to find a function where I can split my column (np array) in vertical direction, every time +-three zeros are detected (I use a sensor that resets the values to 0 everytime a single measurement is finished). And keep the last one of these zeros, so that every column starts with the value zero.
Like so;

Initial column:
0
1
4
2
3
4
7
0
6
0
0
0
6
4
6
3
0
0
0
7

should split into ;

Column1:
0
1
4
2
3
4
7
0
6

Column 2:
0
6
4
6
3

Column 3:
0
7

The reason I want this to work, is because my graph currently looks like this:
[image: Current graph]

I want the peaks that are now in series to be parallel, like so;
[image: Goals]

I hope you can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a [vertical split function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html).
But you are not just splitting but also deleting rows. So you want to detect when there are 3 (or more) zeros after each other, split at the start and before the end of zeros than cut the zeros out.

Here it is implemented:

```
data = np.array((0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7))
data = np.vstack(data)

column = data[:,0]
where_to_split = []
start = 0

while start < len(column):
    
    end = 0
    while start+end < len(column):
        if column[start+end] != 0:
            break
        end += 1 

    if end > 2:
        where_to_split.extend([start, start+end-1])
        start += end

    start += 1

result = np.vsplit(data, where_to_split)[::2]
```

The result is a list of arrays.